# Unable to set up SSH key for github repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I have created following ssh key in ubuntu at path `/home/ubuntu/.ssh` where `ubuntu` is my user name:
[image]

I added this key to my ubuntu user login on github:

[image]

However when I try to clone, it gives me Permission Denied error:

[image]

PS:

Permissions of id_rsa:

[image]

Comment: What are the permissions on `id_rsa`? Who's the owner?

Comment: added the screen shot.  root user seem to be an owner.

Comment: How did you generate the key? Your own user should be the owner.

Comment: `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh`

Answer (score 1):

When running a git / ssh client, you're using your own user's permission instead of `root`. So your user (`ubuntu`) needs to have the permission to the keys. Apparently you generated your keys with `sudo`, which does everything as the `root` user. That makes `root` own your ssh keys here.

Just change the ownership of everything in your `.ssh/` to yourself:

```bash
sudo chown -R $USER: $HOME/.ssh
```